# How can I focus on a certain portion of GoogleMap

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on a GoogleMap Activity. In my `onMapReady(...)`, I want to focus on a particular part of the map. I was able to represent this part on the map by using a [polygon](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon) as shown below:

```
Polygon polygon = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(6.455770, 3.514651), new LatLng(6.455087, 3.547698), new LatLng(6.430651, 3.541926), new LatLng(6.435339, 3.513149))
            .strokeColor(Color.RED));
```

The above code snippet worked perfectly, exactly the way I expected. However, I want to go an extra length. I want to fade out every other part of the map (probably with a dull overlay) and focus on that polygon alone. By "*focus on that polygon alone*", this screenshot from the 'Via' app best represents what I mean.

[image]

I want to create a dull mask everywhere on the map except the area within the polygon. I searched the documentation for methods I can use to achieve this but it was futile. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any "blur" in the screenshot you posted. Maybe an "opacity layer", which you could easily achieve by displaying another Polygon around your existing area Polygon with a black background color and opacity at 0.2 or something like that...

Comment: Thank you @MrUpsidown. What I meant was an overlay of some sort. 'Blur' was the wrong word, I'll edit the question right now.

Comment: The answer is still appropriate. Create another Polygon that covers either the rest of the viewport (if the map cannot be panned/zoomed) or that covers the rest of the world and you will have what you are after.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801549/6950238) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MrUpsideDown's answer works 100% but I decided to add an Android implementation of how I was able to solve this problem since the context of the question is Android.

> The overall idea is to cover the **entire** map with a Polygon. This polygon would have a fillColor (which can be a dull colour). To highlight the places you want to focus on, you can simply add holes to the polygon.

We can break this down into three simple steps:

1. Get the coordinates of all the places you want to focus on. Each of the places you want to focus on should be an List of LatLngs. Here's an example:

   ```
       public List<List<LatLng>> allMyHoles(){

           // list to hold all holes
           List<List<LatLng>> holes = new ArrayList<>();

           // location one
           List<LatLng> hole1 = new ArrayList<>();
           hole1.add(new LatLng(51.509959, -0.181208));
           hole1.add(new LatLng(51.511288, -0.158354));
           hole1.add(new LatLng(51.506520, -0.152773));
           hole1.add(new LatLng(51.512158, -0.174572));
           hole1.add(new LatLng(51.522434, -0.197979));

           holes.add(hole1);

           // location 2
           List<LatLng> hole2 = new ArrayList<>();
           hole2.add(new LatLng(51.500216, -0.166685));
           hole2.add(new LatLng(51.544934, -0.152737));
           hole2.add(new LatLng(51.547666, -0.152949));
           hole2.add(new LatLng(51.544964, -0.156916));
           hole2.add(new LatLng(51.535335, -0.14565));
           hole2.add(new LatLng(51.533599, -0.156538));

           holes.add(hole2);

           return holes;

       }
   ```

At this stage, all the holes you want to create are in a list of lists called holes.

 2. Cover the entire earth in a Polygon and give it a dull colour: To achieve this, we need to get the boundaries of the earth. Don't worry about the implementation, here's a method that returns the LatLng of the whole earth:

```
    private List<LatLng> getEarthlyBound() {
        final float delta = 0.01f;

        return new ArrayList<LatLng>() {{
            add(new LatLng(90 - delta, -180 + delta));
            add(new LatLng(0, -180 + delta));
            add(new LatLng(-90 + delta, -180 + delta));
            add(new LatLng(-90 + delta, 0));
            add(new LatLng(-90 + delta, 180 - delta));
            add(new LatLng(0, 180 - delta));
            add(new LatLng(90 - delta, 180 - delta));
            add(new LatLng(90 - delta, 0));
            add(new LatLng(90 - delta, -180 + delta));
        }};
    }
```

3. The last step is to create our PolygonOptions object and add it to the map. Since we already have access to the LatLng dimensions of the earth as well as the holes we want to create in it, we can proceed to create our PolyOptions object, follow the function below:

```
private PolygonOptions createPolygonWithHoles(List<List<LatLng>> holes) {

    PolygonOptions polyOptions = new PolygonOptions()
            .fillColor(0x33000000) /*sample fill color*/
            .addAll(getEarthlyBound()) /*the bounds of the earth*/
            .strokeColor(0xFF000000) /*sample stroke color*/
            .strokeWidth(5); /*sample stroke width*/

    for (List<LatLng> hole : holes) {
        polyOptions.addHole(hole);
    }

    return polyOptions;
}
```

Right after this, we can now add our PolyOptions object to the map like this:

```
mMap.addPolygon(createPolygonWithHoles(allMyHoles()));
```

I hope this helps someone. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (using the Javascript API). The idea would be exactly the same in Android.

On a Mercator projection, the maximum north latitude is not 90, but something around 85.05113. In JavaScript you can do:

```
Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI)) * 180 / Math.PI;
```

This way you can find the real north and south edges of the projection (to cover the whole world with your Polygon).

Then you need to create at least 1 Polygon (with a hole in it) to achieve the desired effect. If you need the area to be colored, you will then need a second Polygon (see second snippet).

```js
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    
    // Find the min/max latitude
    var maxLat = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    var worldCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-maxLat, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(maxLat, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(maxLat, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-maxLat, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-maxLat, 0)];

    var EuropeCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.7, -23.7),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.7, 44.8),
    new google.maps.LatLng(71.8, 44.8),
    new google.maps.LatLng(71.8, -23.7)];

    // Construct the polygon
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [worldCoords, EuropeCoords],
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor: '#000000',
        fillOpacity: 0.2
    });

    poly.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {

  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async differ src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Second example, with colored area Polygon:

```js
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.886436490787712, -70.2685546875),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
    
    // Find the min/max latitude
    var maxLat = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    var worldCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-maxLat, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(maxLat, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(maxLat, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-maxLat, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-maxLat, 0)];

    var EuropeCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.7, -23.7),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.7, 44.8),
    new google.maps.LatLng(71.8, 44.8),
    new google.maps.LatLng(71.8, -23.7)];

    // Construct the outer polygon
    var worldPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [worldCoords, EuropeCoords],
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor: '#000000',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        map: map
    });

    // Construct the inner polygon
    var europePoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: EuropeCoords,
        strokeColor: 'red',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: 'yellow',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        map: map
    });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {

  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async differ src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**Note**: The Android SDK even makes it easier. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/Polygon) mentions:

> A polygon can be convex or concave, it may span the 180 meridian and it can have holes that are not filled in.
>
> **Holes**: A hole is a region inside the polygon that is not filled. A hole is specified in exactly the same way as the outline. A hole must be fully contained within the outline. Multiple holes can be specified, however overlapping holes are not supported.