# Is there a way to highlight an area within a city using the google map api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have set up the google maps on my app, and I wanted to show the user the area of where they are within a city like this,

[image]

This is however a desktop browser and I wanted to implement in on my app.

This is so I can get an area name rather than a whole city because it's would be too broad, or a address which will be too specific.

This is my `onMapReady` after getting user's location

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLogitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Current Location"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 14.0f));
}
```

Comment: you can make a polygan for google map api but you need to know the bounds of your city or any area by using LatLngBounds

Comment: @PayamKokabi like I said I didn't want to outline a city just an area within a city, also this would be a pain because there would just be too much

Comment: @Kristofer you still need to know the bounds provide the coordinates, the map won't magically do it for you. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes

Comment: @Leo how does google maps do this then? I mean theres literally thousands of areas that they would have to do this manually by hand for.

Comment: @Kristofer Google does it exactly like that. Do you really think thousands of areas is a lot? Think again...

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49801549/6950238).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the latitude and longitude coordinates of the required area and store in DB and the coordinates from DB and just draw the polygon on the map.

Make sure that check your Android manifest
Note the following elements in your app's AndroidManifest.xml file:

Add a meta-data element to embed the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Add a meta-data element specifying your API key. The sample accompanying this tutorial maps the value for the API key to a string google_maps_key. When you build your app, Gradle copies the API key from your project's Gradle.properties file to the string value.

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
  android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.polygons">
```

Below is a complete example of a manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs.
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.polygons.PolyActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Add a map**
Display a map, using the Maps SDK for Android.

Add a `<fragment>` element to your activity's layout file, activity_maps.xml. This element defines a SupportMapFragment to act as a container for the map and to provide access to the GoogleMap object. The tutorial uses the Android support library version of the map fragment, to ensure backward compatibility with earlier versions of the Android framework.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.polygons.PolyActivity" />
```

In your activity's onCreate() method, set the layout file as the content view. Get a handle to the map fragment by calling FragmentManager.findFragmentById(). Then use getMapAsync() to register for the map callback:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    // Get the SupportMapFragment and request notification when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

Implement the OnMapReadyCallback interface and override the onMapReady() method. The API invokes this callback when the GoogleMap object is available, so you can add objects to the map and further customize it for your app:

```
public class PolyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
                OnMapReadyCallback,
                GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener,
                GoogleMap.OnPolygonClickListener {

    // More code goes here, including the onCreate() method described above.

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        // Add polylines and polygons to the map. This section shows just
        // a single polyline. Read the rest of the tutorial to learn more.
        Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .clickable(true)
                .add(
                        new LatLng(-35.016, 143.321),
                        new LatLng(-34.747, 145.592),
                        new LatLng(-34.364, 147.891),
                        new LatLng(-33.501, 150.217),
                        new LatLng(-32.306, 149.248),
                        new LatLng(-32.491, 147.309)));

        // Position the map's camera near Alice Springs in the center of Australia,
        // and set the zoom factor so most of Australia shows on the screen.
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-23.684, 133.903), 4));

        // Set listeners for click events.
        googleMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(this);
        googleMap.setOnPolygonClickListener(this);
    }
}
```